# warning C26812: The enum type 'utils::TwilightTypes' is unscoped. Prefer 'enum class' over 'enum' (Enum.3)

Tags: c++, enums

I'm developing a library using Visual Studio 2019 and C++ on Windows 10.

I have the header file "Utils.h" with this declaration:

```
namespace utils {

    enum TwilightTypes
    {
        Civil,
        Nautical,
        Astronomical
    };
```

And in the header file "TheSun.h" this class that uses the enum:

```
#pragma once
#include "Utils.h"

class TheSun
{
private:

public:

    // 50. Twilight
    utils::RiseSetTime Twilight(
        utils::TwilightTypes type,
        utils::dateTime date,
        double longitude,
        char longOrientation,
        double latitude,
        char latOrientation);
};
```

But, in the implementation of that method, in file "TheSun.cpp" I get the following warning:

> warning C26812: The enum type 'utils::TwilightTypes' is unscoped.
> Prefer 'enum class' over 'enum' (Enum.3).

I have changed the declaration of the enum to:

```
namespace utils {

    enum class TwilightTypes
    {
        Civil,
        Nautical,
        Astronomical
    };
```

But I get the same warning.

How can I remove this warning?

I have also move the enum declaration to the header file "TheSun.h", and I get the same warning.

I have only one enum in this solution.

I always clean and rebuild the entire solution.

From Microsoft documentation, [here](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#enum3-prefer-class-enums-over-plain-enums) is the explanation of the warning:

> **Reason**
>
> To minimize surprises: traditional enums convert to int too readily.
>
> **Enforcement**
>
> (Simple) Warn on any non-class `enum` definition.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Are you sure you don't have another unscoped enum causing the warning? Or maybe clean and rebuild the project(s)?

Comment: Yes. I did it. And I get the same warning.

Comment: Weird. Not wishing to insult you, but have you tried right-clicking on the use place of the enum in your cpp file and then following the "goto definition" link? Maybe there's a rogue declaration somewhere.

Comment: I have only one enum in the whole solution. If I select the type in the method declaration and press F12 I go to the enum declaration.